# Autocomplete and ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I load a string array using `$.getJSON` to use it as values in a jquery ui autocomplete. I can't get it to work.

Code (the success function is being called properly and I see the alert):

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON(baseUri + 'truck/models/', {}, function (data) {
        $("#ModelName").autocomplete({ 
                source: function( request, response ) {
                    alert(data);
                    response(data);
        }
        });
    });
});
```

Content returned by the server:

```
["KIRUNA K350","MAFI","SISU TR180","SISU TRX242","SVETRUCK 32T","VOLVO A25D","VOLVO A25E","VOLVO A40","VOLVO BMl120","VOLVO BML90"]
```

Error that I get when I type in the input box:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined

Comment: What kind of code do you want to see? `data` is exactly the content that I described (I used chrome dev tools to copy it). The content-type used is `application/json`. The input (#ModelName) is just a simple input:text tag.

Comment: sorry miss-read your code, why are youy running a function at setting of the source?  $("#ModelName").autocomplete({ source: data}); would work just fine?

Comment: because that didn't work and then I started to try all alternatives described in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are just doing the ajax fetch for the autocomplete options on page load so no need to use a function for the source you can just do:

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON(baseUri + 'truck/models/', {}, function (data) {
        $("#ModelName").autocomplete({ 
                source: data
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: it was the first thing that I tried ;) Same error. Is something wrong with my string array?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/dTyvy/1/ If your data is really that format it shouldn't be a problem.  Check your ajax request and make sure you are really getting what you think back.

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure you set the object value

Thus

({source: data});

see fiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/dDCEW/

Answer (score 0):

I had another plugin which defined `menu` in the jQuery context. I removed that plugin and everything works fine know. Kind of nasty, huh?